# How do I force Rails to use the version of Ruby (managed with rbenv) that I want?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed rbenv and ruby-build. Then I installed ruby 1.9.2p290. Everything was looking good.

```
$ cd my_rails_app
$ ruby -v
1.9.2p290
$ rails server
...
[2011-10-04 13:51:01] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-10-04 13:51:01] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10) [universal-darwin11.0]
...
```

But when I run my app, it is still using ruby 1.8.7. (methods that exist in 1.9 fail). Everything in rails/console acts like 1.8, and within IRB acts like 1.9.

How can I force my app to use 1.9?

I am familiar with RVM, I'm specifically asking about rbenv.

Comment: What does "when I run my app" mean? What app server are you using?

Comment: I'm running it locally, using WEBrick. I experience the same problems using rails/console as well. I updated my answer to show the specific server output referencing 1.8.7

Comment: Those scripts reference `/usr/bin/env`. What does `/usr/bin/env ruby -v` tell you?

Comment: `/usr/bin/env ruby -v` -> `ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.1.0]`

Answer (score 5):

Did you install Rails with `bundle install`? If so, note that Bundler does not add the executables into Ruby's executable directory.

Instead, use binstubs or `bundle exec` ([documentation](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html)):

```
bundle exec rails server
```

In case you did not install Rails with Bundler, you probably should do an `rbenv rehash` to update the executable shims. Then `rails server` should work fine. However, this will only work if Rails was installed with Rubygems directly, so it is an unreliable way of invoking Rails.

Comment: WebRick just kept starting with 1.8.7! This worked for me. Thanks.